# What's a good design to handle multiple global hotkeys?

Tags: c#, hotkeys

### I'm struggling to think of a good design to handle multiple global hotkeys.

Say I have three different functions bound to three different global hotkeys...

1. Play Song       | Ctrl + P
2. Skip Song       | Ctrl + N
3. Increase Volume | Ctrl + V

What's a good, effective way to check if the hotkey pressed conforms to a certain function? I'm using a class very similar to this: http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207

Should I create a new instance of the hotkey class for each hotkey?

```
Hotkey hotkey = new Hotkey();
hotkey.RegisterHotkey(Shortcut.ModifierKeys.Control, Keys.F10);

hotkey.KeyPressed += ((s, args) =>
{
    //Do Something!
});
```

Or should I have an enum with different hotkey functions and manage it from within the hotkey class to prevent multiple instances (seems wasteful but easy). Thanks for any advice / help in advance.

Comment: You'll need to rethink this a bit.  Whenever the user pastes from the clipboard when running another program, by using the standard  Ctrl+V keystroke, she didn't actually ask to increase the volume.  She really meant to paste.  Using shortcut keystrokes like this is *very* inappropriate for RegisterHotKey.

Comment: The examples where contrived. Sorry for any ambiguity, someone else expressed a similar concern earlier too. I'll try and be more clear in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would opt for creating a separate instance of the class for each different function, as the Command Pattern seems like a good fit here. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) for some more info.

Comment: This is my preferred design pattern because it's very legible and easy to implement. Just to clarify you would opt that I create a new instance of the Hotkey class basically repeating the snippet I provided above with different statements in the event callback?

Comment: Alex, kinda, yes. I followed a very similar design in a recent application where I kept a dictionary mapping Hotkeys to delegates over which I then iterate and hook everything up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dean, I appreciate it. And you too Joey, thanks for the confirmation. Joey, I would very much like to see an example using code of how you went about mapping hotkeys to delegates if you could spare some time for me.

Comment: Alex: [here](https://github.com/ygra/Diablo3ItemCollage/blob/master/ItemCollageUI/Form1.cs#L36) (line 36 and following). This is all a bit rough; I didn't really get to clean up properly, but I guess it's good enough for now.

Comment: Thank you Joey. I'm sorry I cannot give you any reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the hotkey class static?

```
 Hotkey.Register(modifier, key, callback)
```

and keep them in a list within the class?

Also, I would recommend adding more modifiers to your hotkeys. All of yours are assigned to a common task: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = Print, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = New and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> = Paste

Comment: I was torn between this method and using the command pattern as Dean just informed me. I didn't think about passing a callback as an argument, that's a good design in my opinion. And the hotkey references where contrived.

Comment: You cannot as nicely change hotkeys with this method at runtime, though.